# Finder out of sync with file system

Tags: macos, finder

For the last week or two, Finder is out of sync with the file system. This seems specific to my Downloads folder. Files I download are not visible in Finder, although if I open a terminal I can see the files are there. If I try to open a file from an application, like add an email attachment, then I do see the files in Downloads, but not in Finder itself. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try a restart already?

Answer (score 3):

You can restart finder by holding `Command+Option` while right-clicking the Finder dock icon, and then selecting `Relaunch` from the menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the same problem as the OP and this finally fixed it for me. Now, what causes Finder to go out of sync in the first place? That would be interesting to know too...